# Font Awesome Fonts Not Found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am using font awesome in my rails 4 bootstrap app.

My google developer tools is showing an error that is 404 not found for the fonts.

I have the sass gem (4.2.0) installed and require font-awesome in my application.

Does anyone know how to resolve this error? The icons were displaying properly until a few days ago - I didn't change anything in the relevant code during that period.

Thank you

Comment: Just use the cdn. It's one line. It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this [font-awesome](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails) gem in your app and the **require font-awesome** in your application.css